# Is spectral leakage a random variable?

Tags: time-series, computational-statistics, spectral-analysis

Spectral leakage (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_leakage) is obviously a function of several factors, including its underlying algorithm, precision of variables, etc.

Is there a body of work that explores the behavior and attempts to characterize the noise in spectral leakage? Both frequentist and Bayesian approaches?